# Start Debugging F5 doesn't automatically build

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I used to have the environment optimized for c# but recently I have been doing a mostly c++ work. So after a format, I selected c++ instead. Once in a while I still do some c#/xna stuff so I installed xna as well. Problem is that visual studio does not behave anything like I remember it behaving when I had the environment optimized for c#. The run button no longer compiles the solution. Hell, compiling the solution does nearly nothing... I need to recompile for my changes to take effect. What the hell?

I have tried `Tools > Import and Export Settings > Reset all settings`, reinstalling xna and visual studio and still the F5 does not compile.

**edit:** Turns out that the projects were set to not compile under the configuration options. I never set this though. I found a forum with several people who had the same issue: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsdebug/thread/8657c07a-da08-4a9f-9558-0c9d93c94ce2/

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a number of configurations, it's possible that the currently selected configuration doesn't have the project (you want to auto-build) in it.

For example.

The default configurations are `DEBUG` and `RELEASE` and all the projects (in the solution) are *ticked* against this.

But if you've manually un-ticked a project against one of these configurations OR you've manually added a new project and then un-ticked that project in the configuration .. Visual Studio won't compile those un-ticked projects.

So double check your configuration. (`Right Click on the Solution name => Configuration Manager`).

Answer (score 3):

I hope this will fix your problem: [Start debugging F5 does not build automatically, Visual Studio](http://codereferences.blogspot.in/2012/05/start-debugging-f5-does-not.html).

Comment: In my case the suggestions in the other answers did not work.  However, checking the Configuration Manager I found the project was not set to build.  Ticking Build in the Configuration Manager for the project did the trick for me.  I would suggest checking the project in the Configuration Manager as a first step.  EDIT: Whoops, didn't read Pure Krome's answer properly - same answer as this one.

Answer (score 2):

First check what should happen when you run a project. To do this, open `Tools > Options`, `Projects and Solutions`, `Build and Run`, and check that you have selected for the *On Run, when projects are out of date* option:

[image]

Make sure you have selected `Always Build`...

Answer (score 1):

To change you settings:

1. Tools -> Import and Export Settings
2. Choose: Import selected environment settings
3. Save you settings if you want
4. You are then presented with a set of default settings to choose from (General, C++, C#)

Comment: He did, that was the problem.